# height returns 0 inside directive with anguarJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get the height of a div with height auto.
When I view the element with element-inspector from within chrome it gives a height.

The problem is that with console.log it returns 0.

I have tried innerHeight and outerHeight both don't work.

here is my code:

```
var vAlign = angular.module("vAlign", [])
.directive('vAlign', function() {
    return {
        restrict : "AC",
        link: function(scope, e){

            var elementHeight = e.height();
            var parentHeight = e.parent().height();
            var finalHeight = parentHeight - elementHeight /2;

            e.css('marginTop', finalHeight);

            console.log(elementHeight);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: My guess is whatever is giving it it's height hasn't done so by that point in time.

Comment: That's what I think too. Just can't find a solution to it..

Comment: I've never messed with it, but, isn't there some priority system you can tap into with directives? I wonder if making your directive get parsed last would help.

Comment: I am pretty new to angularjs. I am reading up the angularjs documentation about scope apply and watch maybe that can help.

Comment: What gives the div it's height? an image? static text? text from a scope property?

Comment: I have multiple divs with an icon and text inside. But Already got it working thanks mate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put it in a `$timeout` and it will run post-render:

```
var vAlign = angular.module("vAlign", [])
  .directive('vAlign', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict : "AC",
        link: function(scope, e){
            $timeout(function() {
              var elementHeight = e.height();
              var parentHeight = e.parent().height();
              var finalHeight = parentHeight - elementHeight /2;

              e.css('marginTop', finalHeight);

              console.log(elementHeight);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: isn't by virtue of leaving out the compile definition and providing just the link function, that serves as the post-link function?- http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/28/compile-pre-and-post-linking-in-angularjs.aspx

Comment: upon further research you are right - I guess the $timeout may be the best way to ensure something happens "post-render"

Comment: You're doing any scope related work in the $timeout, so you can just use setTimeout, and save a digest cycle.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases where you're running into a race condition, rather than trying a `$timeout` solution, you can leverage the angular.element's `ready()` call.

```
#coffeescript
.directive 'vAlign', ->
   dir = 
      link: ($scope, elem, attrs)->
         elem.ready( /*insert function here*/ )
```

Comment: Hmm.. I tried your code. It still seem to return 0.

Comment: Oh nevermind it does work too had a typo.. (facepalm)

Comment: I'd stick with the `$timeout` solution then.  Or if you really wanted to get fancy, assuming that the content inside the `elem` might change, you can set up a `$scope.$watch alwaysRunFunc` type approach.  The downside is that it isn't as performant.

Comment: I am using e.ready now. When I get more advanced I'll try and use your fancy approach if needed. Many thanks!